# How to set meta_query with OR condition with the main where clause condition

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a meta key with the name of `_custom_product_catalog_number` and I wanted to add functionality to people can search product with this the catalog number.

I added code following code in functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_post_search');
function modify_post_search($query) 
{
if($query->is_search)
{
$s="c2500";//$s=$_GET['s'];
    $query->set('meta_query', [
        [
            'key' => '_custom_product_catalog_number',
            'value' => $s,
            'compare' => '='
        ]
    ]);
}
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  dsl_posts.ID 
FROM dsl_posts  
   INNER JOIN dsl_postmeta ON ( dsl_posts.ID = dsl_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( dsl_posts.ID NOT IN (
      SELECT object_id FROM dsl_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (6) 
) ) 
AND (((dsl_posts.post_title LIKE '%c2500%') OR (dsl_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%c2500%') OR (dsl_posts.post_content LIKE '%c2500%')))  

AND ( /* replace AND with OR */
  ( dsl_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_product_catalog_number' AND dsl_postmeta.meta_value = 'c2500' ) ) 

AND dsl_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (dsl_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR dsl_posts.post_status = 'wc-want-be-returned' OR dsl_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY dsl_posts.ID 
ORDER BY dsl_posts.post_title LIKE '%c2500%' DESC, dsl_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

How i can replace `AND` keyword with `OR` before `( dsl_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_product_catalog_number'` so I can get results with `OR` condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["WP Query Args - Title or Meta Value"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178484/wp-query-args-title-or-meta-value)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_post_search');
    function modify_post_search($query) 
    {
        $query->set( 'meta_query',  array(
       'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
          'key'     => '_my_custom_key',
          'value'   => 'Value I am looking for',
          'compare' => '='
       ),
      array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_2',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 2',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_my_custom_key_3',
            'value'   => 'Value I am looking for 3',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

    return $query;
    }
```

For more help see this link : [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Comment: HI dinesh, OR Condition will come between meta query not replace with outside of AND condition. I need code like  OR (AND will replace with OR) ( ( dsl_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_product_catalog_number' AND dsl_postmeta.meta_value = 'c2500' ) )

Comment: See the above answer i have modified it.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, how we can replace AND ( ( dsl_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_product_catalog_number' AND dsl_postmeta.meta_value = 'c2500' ) ) ---TO--- OR ( ( dsl_postmeta.meta_key = '_custom_product_catalog_number' AND dsl_postmeta.meta_value = 'c2500' ) )